# What is wrong with this hook?

Tags: groovy, bitbucket, hook

I am currently working on Scriptrunner for bitbucket. I made a pre-receive hook that check the push, if there is a file named "conanfile.py" it checks the inside of the file and compare it with a regex I made. My problem is that whenever I try to push to test this, my terminal tells me there is a mistake :

```
Total 13 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Push blocked
remote: Conanfile.py lines starting with "self.requires" should match regex
To https://bitbucket.ecatools.io/scm/ttdo/test_branch.git
 ! [remote rejected] testscript -> testscript (pre-receive hook declined)
```

While Scriptrunner tells me that everything is fine :

[image: screenshot of Scriptrunner saying that the hook works well]

I am quite lost at what to do and I am here asking for help please.

I tried several ways of doing this while learning Groovy, here is the code of the pre-receive hook (i deleted the import to not take too much space, tell me if you need them) :

```
@ShortTextInput(label = 'regex', description = 'Regex expression used to verify file content')
String regexValue
def pattern = Pattern.compile(".*requires\\(\"[^\\d|_|\\-](\\S)+/\\[(\\d)(\\.\\d)*\\]@(xxx|xxxxx)/stable\"")

def commitService = ComponentLocator.getComponent(CommitService)
def contentService = ComponentLocator.getComponent(ContentService)

def commits = refChanges.getCommits(repository) as List<Commit>

// filePaths to commit Id, if file was modified in multiple commits, take the last commit id
def filePaths = [:] as Map<String, String>
commits.reverseEach { commit ->
    def changesRequest = new ChangesRequest.Builder(repository, commit.id).build()
    commitService.streamChanges(changesRequest) { Change change ->
        if (change.path.toString().endsWith("conanfile.py")) {
            filePaths[change.path.toString()] = commit.id
        }
        true
    }
}

def result = filePaths.keySet().collect { filePath ->
    def fileStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    contentService.streamFile(repository, filePaths[filePath], filePath) {
        fileStream
    }
    fileStream.toString()
}.every {
    it.split("\n").any { line ->
        line.startsWith("self.requires") && pattern.matcher(line).find()
    }
}

result ? RepositoryHookResult.accepted('push approved') : RepositoryHookResult.rejected('Push blocked', 'Conanfile.py lines starting with "self.requires" should match regex')
```

Comment: `whenever I try to push to test this, my terminal tells me there is a mistake` - no this line is saying that hook executed successfully but rejected commit.